# Передача данных от фрагмента к активности. Принимаю нулевое значение

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment, android-intent, android-bundle

Код кнопки, которая находится во фрагменте(который в свою очередь находится в главной активности) по нажатию на которую осуществляется передача данных:

`solve = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);`

```
    solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((a.getText().toString().equals("")) & (b.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    & (c.getText().toString().equals(""))) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "no_koef", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            } else {
                if (a.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    aq = 1.0;
                    a.setText("1");
                } else {
                    aq = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());
                }
                if (b.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    bq = 1.0;
                    b.setText("1");
                } else {
                    bq = Double.parseDouble(b.getText().toString());
                }
                if (c.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    cq = 0.0;
                    c.setText("0");
                } else {
                    cq = Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString());
                }

                dq = ((bq * bq) - 4 * aq * cq);
                d.setText(String.valueOf(dq));
                if (dq < 0) {
                    String no_roots = "Корней нет";
                    x1.setText(no_roots);
                    x2.setText(no_roots);
                } else {
                    x1q = Math.rint(100.0 * (((-1.0) * bq + Math.sqrt(dq)) / (2 * aq))) / (100.0);
                    x2q = Math.rint(100.0 * (((-1.0) * bq - Math.sqrt(dq)) / (2 * aq))) / (100.0);

                    x1.setText(Double.toString(x1q));
                    x2.setText(Double.toString(x2q));
                }

                Intent sender = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
                sender.putExtra("check1", Double.toString(dq));

        }};`
```

Код кнопки (в том же фрагменте), открывающий вторую активность

```
more = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    more.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            Intent sender = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(sender);
        }

        });
```

Код, во второй активности, принимающий и устанавливающий в `textView4` (который находится в `XML` разметке второй активности) отправленные данные:

`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Double koefd = extras.getDouble("check1");
        t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t4.setText(Double.toString(koefd));`

В итоге, в `textView4` (`t4`) либо ничего не отображается, либо отображается `0.0`, в зависимости от того, какой тип данных я принимаю (`String` и `Double` соответственно). Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где тут фрагмент, где активити, зачем вам интент, коий вы не используете и где t4 тоже не ясно. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, разъяснил где что, но немного не понял, что Вы имеете ввиду под "интент, который не используется". Я, насколько понял, его в кнопке объявил и сразу с помощью него отправил во вторую активность данные с помощью putExtra.

Comment: Вы разные интенты используете. Запускаете пустой. См. ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы при нажатии на разные кнопки создаёте два разных интента. В первом случае вы в него кладёте данные и не запускаете по нему активити. Во втором случае вы запускаете активити с пустым интентом.

Засим вам, очевидно, надо складывать данные и запускать активити одним и тем же интентом. Так что сделайте просто ваш интент переменной фрагмента. Т.е. поместите `Intent sender` на уровень класса и используйте в обработчиках именно эту переменную, а не создавайте новую.

Comment: Объявил `Intent` в `OnCreate`-е, таким образом: `final Intent sender = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);` и все заработало. Спасибо)

Comment: @IgorGorokhov, это сработало только потому, что у вас все слушатели в `onCreate` назначены. Если бы вы их в другом месте класса назначали, то интент надо было бы объявить в самом классе, а не в его методах.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка в таге.

```
Intent sender = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
                sender.putExtra("check1", Double.toString(dq));
```

Вы передаете по тагу `"check1"`
а ищите по `"root1"`

```
Double koefd = extras.getDouble("root1");
```

Используйте константы.